# How to change colour of individual pixel of UIImage/UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView to which I have applied the filter:

```
testImageView.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest;
```

So that the individual pixels are visible. This UIImageView is within a UIScrollView, and the image itself is 1000x1000. I have used the following code to detect which pixel has been tapped:

I first set up a tap gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *scrollTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured: )];
scrollTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[mainScrollView addGestureRecognizer:scrollTap];
```

Then used the location of the tap to produce the coordinates of the tap by which pixel of the UIImageView is tapped:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:testImageView];

    NSLog(@"%f is X pixel num, %f is Y pixel num ; %f is width of imageview", (touchPoint.x/testImageView.bounds.size.width)*1000, (touchPoint.y/testImageView.bounds.size.width)*1000, testImageView.bounds.size.width);

}
```

I would like to be able to tap a pixel, and have its colour change. However, none of the StackOverflow posts I have found have answers which work or are not outdated. For skilled coders, however, you may be able to help me decipher the older posts to make something that works, or to produce a simple fix on your own using my above code for detecting which pixel of the UIImageView has been tapped.

All help is appreciated.

Edit for originaluser2:

After following originaluser2's post, running the code works perfectly when I run it through his example GitHub project on my physical device. However, when I run the same code in my own app, I am met with the image being replaced with a white space, and the following errors:

```
<Error>: Unsupported pixel description - 3 components, 16 bits-per-component, 64 bits-per-pixel
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateWithData: failed to create delegate.
<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

The code clearly works, as demonstrated by me testing it on my phone. However, the same code has produced a few issues in my own project. Though I have the suspicion that they are all caused by one or two simple central issues. How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Isaac, re: [your recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625477/round-float-to-specific-ending-decimal-point?noredirect=1), what you're trying to do would be more properly called "binning" than "rounding". That might help your research.

Comment: I appreciate the comment! Fortunately, through come amateur wizardry I eventually worked out the code for what I was trying to achieve. But I'll remember the comment for future reference, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You'll want to break this problem up into multiple steps.

1. Get the coordinates of the touched point in the image coordinate system
2. Get the x and y position of the pixel to change
3. Create a bitmap context and replace the given pixel's components with your new color's components.

First of all, to get the coordinates of the touched point in the image coordinate system – you can use a category method that I wrote on `UIImageView`. This will return a `CGAffineTransform` that will map a point from view coordinates to image coordinates – depending on the content mode of the view.

```
@interface UIImageView (PointConversionCatagory)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGAffineTransform viewToImageTransform;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGAffineTransform imageToViewTransform;

@end

@implementation UIImageView (PointConversionCatagory)

-(CGAffineTransform) viewToImageTransform {

    UIViewContentMode contentMode = self.contentMode;

    // failure conditions. If any of these are met – return the identity transform
    if (!self.image || self.frame.size.width == 0 || self.frame.size.height == 0 ||
        (contentMode != UIViewContentModeScaleToFill && contentMode != UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill && contentMode != UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit)) {
        return CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }

    // the width and height ratios
    CGFloat rWidth = self.image.size.width/self.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat rHeight = self.image.size.height/self.frame.size.height;

    // whether the image will be scaled according to width
    BOOL imageWiderThanView = rWidth > rHeight;

    if (contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit || contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill) {

        // The ratio to scale both the x and y axis by
        CGFloat ratio = ((imageWiderThanView && contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit) || (!imageWiderThanView && contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill)) ? rWidth:rHeight;

        // The x-offset of the inner rect as it gets centered
        CGFloat xOffset = (self.image.size.width-(self.frame.size.width*ratio))*0.5;

        // The y-offset of the inner rect as it gets centered
        CGFloat yOffset = (self.image.size.height-(self.frame.size.height*ratio))*0.5;

        return CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(ratio, ratio), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xOffset, yOffset));
    } else {
        return CGAffineTransformMakeScale(rWidth, rHeight);
    }
}

-(CGAffineTransform) imageToViewTransform {
    return CGAffineTransformInvert(self.viewToImageTransform);
}

@end
```

There's nothing *too* complicated here, just some extra logic for scale aspect fit/fill, to ensure the centering of the image is taken into account. You could skip this step entirely if your were displaying your image 1:1 on screen.

Next, you'll want to get the x and y position of the pixel to change. This is fairly simple – you just want to use the above category property `viewToImageTransform` to get the pixel in the image coordinate system, and then use `floor` to make the values integral.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewWasTapped:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

...

-(void) imageViewWasTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)tapGesture {

    if (!imageView.image) {
        return;
    }

    // get the pixel position
    CGPoint pt = CGPointApplyAffineTransform([tapGesture locationInView:imageView], imageView.viewToImageTransform);
    PixelPosition pixelPos = {(NSInteger)floor(pt.x), (NSInteger)floor(pt.y)};

    // replace image with new image, with the pixel replaced
    imageView.image = [imageView.image imageWithPixel:pixelPos replacedByColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1.0]];
}
```

Finally, you'll want to use another of my category methods – `imageWithPixel:replacedByColor:` to get out your new image with a replaced pixel with a given color.

```
/// A simple struct to represent the position of a pixel
struct PixelPosition {
    NSInteger x;
    NSInteger y;
};

typedef struct PixelPosition PixelPosition;

@interface UIImage (UIImagePixelManipulationCatagory)

@end

@implementation UIImage (UIImagePixelManipulationCatagory)

-(UIImage*) imageWithPixel:(PixelPosition)pixelPosition replacedByColor:(UIColor*)color {

    // components of replacement color – in a 255 UInt8 format (fairly standard bitmap format)
    const CGFloat* colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    UInt8* color255Components = calloc(sizeof(UInt8), 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) color255Components[i] = (UInt8)round(colorComponents[i]*255.0);

    // raw image reference
    CGImageRef rawImage = self.CGImage;

    // image attributes
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(rawImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(rawImage);
    CGRect rect = {CGPointZero, {width, height}};

    // image format
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerRow = width*4;

    // the bitmap info
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;

    // data pointer – stores an array of the pixel components. For example (r0, b0, g0, a0, r1, g1, b1, a1 .... rn, gn, bn, an)
    UInt8* data = calloc(bytesPerRow, height);

    // get new RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // create bitmap context
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

    // draw image into context (populating the data array while doing so)
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, rawImage);

    // get the index of the pixel (4 components times the x position plus the y position times the row width)
    NSInteger pixelIndex = 4*(pixelPosition.x+(pixelPosition.y*width));

    // set the pixel components to the color components
    data[pixelIndex] = color255Components[0]; // r
    data[pixelIndex+1] = color255Components[1]; // g
    data[pixelIndex+2] = color255Components[2]; // b
    data[pixelIndex+3] = color255Components[3]; // a

    // get image from context
    CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);

    // clean up
    free(color255Components);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(data);

    UIImage* returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];
    CGImageRelease(img);

    return returnImage;
}

@end
```

What this does is first get out the components of the color you want to write to one of the pixels, in a 255 UInt8 format. Next, it creates a new bitmap context, with the given attributes of your input image.

The important bit of this method is:

```
// get the index of the pixel (4 components times the x position plus the y position times the row width)
NSInteger pixelIndex = 4*(pixelPosition.x+(pixelPosition.y*width));

// set the pixel components to the color components
data[pixelIndex] = color255Components[0]; // r
data[pixelIndex+1] = color255Components[1]; // g
data[pixelIndex+2] = color255Components[2]; // b
data[pixelIndex+3] = color255Components[3]; // a
```

What this does is get out the index of a given pixel (based on the x and y coordinate of the pixel) – then uses that index to replace the component data of that pixel with the color components of your replacement color.

Finally, we get out an image from the bitmap context and perform some cleanup.

**Finished Result:**

[image]

---

**Full Project: https://github.com/hamishknight/Pixel-Color-Changing**

Comment: Looking at implementing this now. Will let you know how I get on. Thank you for the extremely detailed reply!

Comment: After running your project on my phone, the code clearly works, so I've marked the question as answered. However, when I ran the same code in my own project, it was met with a couple of errors which I listed in an edit to my main post. Though you have helped me answer the question, I would be very grateful if you could help me solve the issue, as I suspect its cause is quite straight forward.

Comment: @IsaacA What's the image you're using? Sounds like it's in an unsupported format (3 components, 16 bits-per-component, 64 bits-per-pixel). You'll either have to convert it to a supported format (4 components, 8 bits per component, 32 bits per pixel) – or I'll have to add some extra code to handle it. A link to your image would be great for debugging it though.

Comment: @IsaacA Actually, after refreshing myself on the [supported bitmap pixel formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) – it appears 64 bits per pixel is only available on OS X, not iOS. So you'll need to convert your image to an 8 bit per component format. You should be able to do this (fairly) easily in an image editor. In Photoshop, you can select it when creating a new file under "Color Mode: RGB, 8 bit"

Comment: I actually tried making a 32-bit .tif image, but this too produced peculiar errors in the Xcode logs, as well as causing strange colour shifts when I exported the image. Oddly, when I instead produced an 8-bit JPEG, this resulted in your code working perfectly! As is, I expect 8-bit will likely be all I require for my intended purposes. Thanks a lot for the extra help :)

Comment: Ahh, yes I see your 8-bit comment now. Yes, this was definitely the solution it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something"];

CGSize size = originalImage.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

// myColor is an instance of UIColor
[myColor setFill];
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(someX, someY, 1, 1);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```